# What is the fastest method to acquire olive wood?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

I am working on upgrading the Adrestia and need large quantities of wood to do so.

What methods can I employ to yield the largest quantity of wood in the shortest amount of time?

I have been cleaving ships to earn wood, and buying it from blacksmiths where possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method and quickest method in the game:

- Travelling between blacksmiths and buying olive wood

When travelling between backsmiths they will not always stock up, however, you can expect about 4 out of 5 to stock it and you'll generally get 100+ stock

best alternative method:

- Raid and battle boats

Not as efficient as trading.

Other ways to obtain olive wood:

- Complete contracts with a chance of getting olive wood
- Pillage nation chests with a chance of getting olive wood

Personally, when I was trading I would simply continue as normal completing quests and any blacksmith that I encountered or was "only slightly" out of the way would be where I bought my olive wood, although I'm guessing you recently hit level 25 which is why this is now your focus.

Comment: Worth mentioning that looting the war supplies in forts yields wood also. So make sure to loot before you burn them.